# StopStoryboard doesn't... stop the BeginStoryboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I have extracted this piece of code from my project, because I was trying to find a mistake I made which keeps my `BeginStoryboard` from stopping itself. I simplified code as much as possible and still I don't see a problem. What do you think it could be?

```
<Window Width="640" Height="480" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Start" Name="Button" Width="200">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="Storyboard">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation By="150" Duration="0:0:5" Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Button" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:5" Value="Did you click? Because I obviously didn't stop..."/>
                        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <Button Content="Stop">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Try the code yourself, first Button triggers the storyboard, second one is supposed to stop it, but nothing happens, so animation in first Button goes on happily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `BeginStoryboard` is in a different naming scope, so the `StopStoryboard` doesn't see it.

You need to put both triggers in the same collection, like [the MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.stopstoryboard.aspx#exampleToggle).

Comment: Link will open 4.5/4.6 .net version page, which doesn't have example. Switch to 4.0 to see one.