# StopStoryboard doesn't stop endless animation

Tags: wpf, datatrigger, wpf-animation

I'm drawing a `Polygon` on a `Canvas` as a battery indicator. If the battery percentage drops below a threshold value, the polygon should start a pulsing animation, if the percentage rises back above the threshold, the pulsing should stop. For that I am using a `DataTrigger` that binds to a `bool` in the view model that tells me whether or not to run the pulsing animation loop at the moment.

At first, the animation is off, and as soon as the percentage drops, it starts pulsing as intended. But when the percentage levels rise again, I can't find any way to make the pulsing animation stop.

This is my current XAML code:

```xml
<Polygon.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Polygon">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding IsLowPercentage}"
                Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="Pulse">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                AutoReverse="True"
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                From="1"
                                To="0.2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Pulse" />
                    <!--<RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Pulse" />-->
                    <!--<BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                To="1"
                                Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>-->
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Polygon.Style>
```

I found two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19791171), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9176333)) about this which have the same use-case, and `StopStoryboard` seems to do the trick for them, but not for me.

Next to `StopStoryboard`, I also tried `RemoveStoryboard` and another `BeginStoryboard` (because according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30397399) a storyboard automatically stops if the same dependency propery is animated by a new storyboard). The regarding codes are shown in the commented part. I tested all combinations, that is `Stop`, `Remove`, `Begin` alone, `Stop+Remove`, `Stop+Begin`, `Remove+Begin` or `Stop+Remove+Begin` in combination, but nothing seems to work, the pulsing effect just continues forever.

I also considered [different naming scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7930419) as the issue, but my storyboards are even in closer naming scopes (*same* `DataTrigger`) than [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-use-event-triggers-to-control-a-storyboard-after-it-starts?view=netframework-4.8) using `StopStoryboard` from Microsoft themselves, and my code is also very similar to [this other example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-a-property-value-changes?view=netframework-4.8) from Microsoft, but my animation is endless.

I have validated that the `bool` is in fact set to `true` or `false` respectively, and I see that all other values bound to the same view model are displaying the updated values from that view model, so that should be fine.

Everybody seems to be fine using `StopStoryboard`, but something about my code is wrong so it doesn't work for me.

Comment: There's one difference I can think of: I am assigning a **new** viewmodel with where the boolean is `true` or `false`. Could it be that this doesn't count as "exiting" opposing to updating the value in the _same_ view model?

Comment: You could easily try that, couldn't you?

Comment: Not "easily", but yes I will try it when I have time again. It would surprise me though if changing the VM could trigger `EnterActions` but not `ExitActions`...

Comment: Well, it took me less than five minutes to write a short program that tests exactly this case, and (probably surprising) ExitActions doesn't seem to be executed if i change the DataContext.

Comment: I tried using a second `DataTrigger` on `Value=False` with `EnterActions` overriding the storyboard. That didn't work either. I will change my existing VM to contain a function to change the underlying model instead of creating a new VM for a new model. I'll see if that helps.